# Extracting the list of diseases as well as their negation from a physician note using cTAKES

Tags: computational-linguistics, ctakes

E.g. I have the following physician note:

> The patient has diabetes. The patient does not have the flu.

I would like to extract from it the information that `diabetes` and `not flu` are mentioned. How can I do it in [Apache cTAKES](http://ctakes.apache.org/)?

Comment: While support for linguistics software is allowed here, there may not be many, if any, people on this site who have used this one unfortunately.